# Define associative array of arrays

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I want to define an associative array like this

```
var theVar = [
  { "100", [0, 1, 2] },
  { "101", [3, 4, 5] }
]
```

Essentially I want to be able to access an array of three numbers by specifying the custom index.

However, no matter what I try I cannot make it work.

I know I can define it as:

```
theVar["100"] = [0, 1, 2];
theVar["101"] = [1, 2, 3];
```

But I am setting this somewhere else and I'd prefer to be able to set it in a single statement.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
theVar = {
  "100": [0, 1, 2],
  "101": [3, 4, 5]
}
```

might do the trick. You can then access using `theVar["101"]` (or `theVar[101]` for that matter).

(As `var` is also [a keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) in JavaScript, using it as a variable name is very likely to cause problems.)

Comment: This *is* the way to create the js-version of an associative array. It's called Object Literal Notation.

Comment: need a variable after "var" or change array name to a not reserved word

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [JSON](http://json.org) syntax, I think It could inspire the building of your data structures in a way that will be flexible, correct and complex as you want.

[This](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)) page has a lot of information and example that are helpful for you.

For instance look at this:

```
var employees = { "accounting" : [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                                    { "firstName" : "John",  // First element
                                      "lastName"  : "Doe",
                                      "age"       : 23 },

                                    { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                      "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                      "age"       : 32 }
                                  ], // End "accounting" array.                                  
                  "sales"       : [ // Sales is another array in employees.
                                    { "firstName" : "Sally", // First Element
                                      "lastName"  : "Green",
                                      "age"       : 27 },

                                    { "firstName" : "Jim",   // Second Element
                                      "lastName"  : "Galley",
                                      "age"       : 41 }
                                  ] // End "sales" Array.
                } // End Employees
```

Comment: This is is not JSON. This is Object Literal Notation - JSON is a **subset** of this.
The first premise of being able to call anything JSON is that it is contained in a **string**. ;)

Comment: Looks like JSON to me.  Property names must be strings to be proper JSON, but the values do not.  Or is there something else you mean?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation